# How to export one dataframe, which contains +1.048.576 rows, into multiple excel files/sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm planning to import multiple excel files and use append method to obtain a dataframe that contains all of the information I need. However, I am certain that the number of rows in the dataframe will exceed the row limit of excel. Therefore, while exporting the data must be divided and stored in multiple excel sheets or, more preferably, files. How can I perform that?

Comment: Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html `df.loc[a:b]` will slice the dataframe.

Comment: Is excel file/sheets a necessity? You can use `csv` which can be read as excel and it has no limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in for loop while printing out to file. Sample code:

```
number_of_row = 60000

loop_count = int(len(df) / number_of_row)

for cycle in range(loop_count):
    df[cycle*number_of_row:(cycle+1)*number_of_row].to_excel('part-{}.xls'.format(cycle))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using [`numpy.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html), to split your `DataFrame` into chunks.

```
ROW_LIMIT = 1048576
chunks = (len(df) // ROW_LIMIT) + 1
```

#### Splitting into multiple sheets of a single Workbook

```
workbook = pd.ExcelWriter('./output.xlsx')

for i, chunk in enumerate(np.array_split(df, chunks)):
    chunk.to_excel(workbook, sheet_name=f'Sheet{i+1}')
```

#### Splitting into multiple Workbooks

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(np.array_split(df, chunks)):
    chunk.to_excel(f'output{i+1}.xlsx')
```