# How to export to multiple excel sheet of a single csv file through pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a large txt file in python pandas. Now I want to export the csv file to multiple excel as data is too large to fit in a single excel sheet.

I use the following commands:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('basel.txt',delimiter='|')
df.to_excel('basel.txt')
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
****ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 1158008, 18 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384****
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083006?

Answer (score 1):

You can split into chunks and write each chunk in one sheet.
`np.array_split` splits into number of chunks
`np.split` requires an equal division.

```
import numpy as np

nsheets = 10  # you may change it
for i, temp in enumerate(np.array_split(df, nsheets)):
    temp.to_excel('basel.xls', sheet_name=f'sheet_{i}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv('basel.txt', chunksize=chunksize):
    chunk.to_excel('basel_'+str(chunk)+'.excel')
```

you may read the pandas file in chunks and save each chunk in excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can write half of the dataset into a different excel sheet:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('basel.txt',delimiter='|')
df.iloc[:df.shape[0]//2,:].to_excel('basel.xls', sheet_name='First Sheet')
df.iloc[df.shape[0]//2:,:].to_excel('basel.xls', sheet_name='Second Sheet')
```

Comment: after using the above code, I got the following error:  TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheet'

Comment: Sorry, it should be `sheet_name`